# How to reactive css code completion for JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea

users,
a few days ago I deactivated the css code completion for JavaFX-Tags like '-fx-...'. I don't know why it happened but I would like to reactivate the code suggestions or code completion.

I didnt find the option to activate it again. Currently it says "unknown css property".

Would awesome if anyone could help.

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now i fixed it.

Go to preferences > Plugins > activate "Java FX" > Restart > fixed

hope it helps.